# anyway to bring the table style to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to get the Print functionality to look exactly like in other browsers, Using IE11 and Edge as two main suspects now,

For Other browsers, I had used the properties of css

```
 -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
color-adjust : exact;
```

they seem to be working quite good. 
Now my table has bgcolor hard-coded and some have borders, so i am trying everything where i could bring that style to IE.

can't write a separate css because the colors are scattered between the html page. same is with the borders.

what hacks can i try to make it user, even there is less user base on IE, but it still has some

Guidance please

Thanks

Comment: The nostalgia! A decade ago we even started a campaign to boycott IE6 :)  ["what hacks can i try to make it user, even there is less user base on IE, but it still has some"] You may be mistyped it and mean how can you normalize/standardize your style to adapt to different browsers including IE? or How can I display something to IE users asking them to use a different browser? ...

Comment: You could refer to this too : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-color-adjust

Comment: That is where i came from, after that visit i posted my question